# Array.Prototype ForEach Wait For Callback Function To Return In Recursive Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous

I Have a recursive function which loops through the keys of a javascript object. This is used to find all keys with the name "filename". When the condition is matched I need to call a callback function base64 which converts an image to base64. My problem is that this task takes a long time and due it asynchronicity  the loop finishes before it even converts the first image. I've tried using the async library but that didn't work, i'm pretty sure its due to the recursive nature of the function. How can I halt the execution of the foreach loop until the callback has returned a result.

The function is

```
const iterate = (obj) =>
{
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) =>
    {
        if(key === 'filename')
        {
            base64.encode(`https://example.com/${obj[key]}`, { string: true }, (errr, encr) =>
            {
                obj[key] = encr;
            });
        }
        if(typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key] !== null)
        {
            iterate(obj[key]);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: whay are you finding the keys ? you can just check if there is a key as `filename`

Comment: why you want to do that?

Comment: Well i want to check if there are keys called filename and then do some manipulation on that key when i find it. This object containers many nested structures

Comment: Still you dont need to wait for async code to complete in each loop, untill you dont want to do anything from the result of async code before the loop completes you dont need to wait for it.

Comment: But I am using the result of the async code to override the value of obj[key] during the loop. The behavior i was noticing was I was able to get a response from express before my console.logs had finished writing to screen

Comment: Use bluebird + Promise.promisify + Promise.props/.map/.reduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [promisify](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) your method and then await.

```
 const Promise  = require('bluebird');
    let encode = Promise.promisify(base64.encode)

    const iterate = async (obj) =>
    {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) =>
        {
            if(key === 'filename')
            {
                        obj[key] = await encode(`https://example.com/${obj[key]}`, { string: true });
            }
            if(typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key] !== null)
            {
                iterate(obj[key]);
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: With this I am getting an error of  "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function" it is complaining about the line await encode

Comment: did you add bluebird and promisify?

Comment: i did npm i bluebird promisify

Comment: you need to do `npm i bluebird` and then add these two line in your code.

Comment: Yea i've got bluebird version 3.5.3 installed

Answer (score 0):

```
//  SOLUTION 1
const async = require('async');

const iterator = (key, next) => {
  if(key === 'filename') {
      base64.encode(`https://example.com/${obj[key]}`, { string: true }, (errr, encr) => {
          obj[key] = encr;
          return next();
      });
  }
  return next();
};

async.each(Object.keys(obj), iterator, err => callback(err, obj));
```

You can use the `async` library like this. The `iterator` iterates over the keys and if the key is `file`,

```
//  SOLUTION 2
const getObj = (obj, callback) => {
    const { filename } = obj;
    if(!filename) return callback(null, obj);
    base64.encode(`https://example.com/${obj['filename']}`, { string: true }, (errr, encr) => {
      obj['filename'] = encr;
      return callback(errr, obj);
    });
};

getObj(obj, (err, newObj) => {
  // use any callback function that uses variable newObj
  // you can change obj by commenting out the line below
  // obj = newObj
});
```

Or since `obj` is an object, you can directly lookup the key and use it in a function that runs a callback.

Comment: Your first solution gives me an error where iterator is not found. Your second solution does not actually change the old object and the object returned by the callback does not seem to change the data at all. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Hey, fixed the solution. Some typographical error in solution 1 and returned values in solution 2. Please let me know if it works